# AI does not follow the waypoints

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game which requires the enemy to follow wayoints. The problem now is that it does not seem to want to enter the 'slow' state and therefore not go to the next waypoint. I think it might have something to do with the 'waitforseconds' but im not quite sure if that's the problem. The enemy also moves upwards without any clear reason. The script I'm using is converted from Javascript, so the problem might originate from that aswell.

I know this is a big wall of questions, but I've been trying to fix this for several days(maybe even a week) without any success. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Bloop : MonoBehaviour {

// Converted from UnityScript to C# at http://www.M2H.nl/files/js_to_c.php - by Mike Hergaarden
// Do test the code! You usually need to change a few small bits.       //   This is a very simple waypoint system.
//   Each bit is explained in as much detail as possible for people (like me!) who need every single line explained.
//
//   As a side note to the inexperienced (like me at the moment!), you can delete the word "public" on any variable to see it in the inspector for debugging.
//
//   I am sure there are issues with this as is, but it seems to work pretty well as a demonstration.
//
//STEPS:
//1. Attach this script to a GameObject with a RidgidBody and a Collider.
//2. Change the "Size" variable in "Waypoints" to the number of waypoints you want to use.
//3. Drop your waypoint objects on to the empty variable slots.
//4. Make sure all your waypoint objects have colliders. (Sphere Collider is best IMO).
//5. Click the checkbox for "is Trigger" to "On" on the waypoint objects to make them triggers.
//6. Set the Size (radius for sphere collider) or just Scale for your waypoints.
//7. Have fun! Try changing variables to get different speeds and such.
//
//   Disclaimer:
//   Extreeme values will start to mess things up.
//   Maybe someone more experienced than me knows how to improve it.
//   Please correct me if any of my comments are incorrect.




public float accel=0.8f; //This is the rate of accelleration after the function "Accell()" is called. Higher values will cause the object to reach the "speedLimit" in less time.

public float inertia=0.9f; //This is the the amount of velocity retained after the function "Slow()" is called. Lower values cause quicker stops. A value of "1.0f" will never stop. Values above "1.0f" will speed up.

public float speedLimit= 10.0f; //This is as fast the object is allowed to go.

public float minSpeed=1.0f; //This is the speed that tells the functon "Slow()" when to stop moving the object.
//public float rotation=1.0f;
public Quaternion rotation;

public float stopTime=1.0f; //This is how long to pause inside "Slow()" before activating the function "Accell()" to start the script again.

//This variable "currentSpeed" is the major player for dealing with velocity.
//The "currentSpeed" is mutiplied by the variable "accel" to speed up inside the function "accell()".
//Again, The "currentSpeed" is multiplied by the variable "inertia" to slow things down inside the function "Slow()".
public float currentSpeed=0.0f;

//The variable "functionState" controlls which function, "Accell()" or "Slow()", is active. "0" is function "Accell()" and "1" is function "Slow()".
public float functionState=0.0f;

//The next two variables are used to make sure that while the function "Accell()" is running, the function "Slow()" can not run (as well as the reverse).
public bool  accelState;
public bool  slowState;

//This variable will store the "active" target object (the waypoint to move to).
public Transform waypoint;

//This is the speed the object will rotate to face the active Waypoint.
public float rotationDamping=6.0f;

//If this is false, the object will rotate instantly toward the Waypoint. If true, you get smoooooth rotation baby!
bool smoothRotation= true;

//This variable is an array. []< that is an array container if you didnt know. It holds all the Waypoint Objects that you assign in the inspector.
public Transform[] waypoints;

//This variable keeps track of which Waypoint Object, in the previously mentioned array variable "waypoints", is currently active.
private int WPindexPointer;





//Functions! They do all the work.
//You can use the built in functions found here: [url]http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html[/url]
//Or you can declare your own! The function "Accell()" is one I declared.
//You will want to declare your own functions because theres just certain things that wont work in "Update()". Things like Coroutines: [url]http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/index.Coroutines_26_Yield.html[/url]


//The function "Start()" is called just before anything else but only one time.
void  Start (){
    functionState = 0; //When the script starts set "0" or function Accell() to be active.

}




//The function "Update()" is called every frame. It can get slow if overused.
void  Update (){
    if (functionState == 0) //If functionState variable is currently "0" then run "Accell()". Withouth the "if", "Accell()" would run every frame.
    {
        Accell ();
    }
    if (functionState == 1) //If functionState variable is currently "1" then run "Slow()". Withouth the "if", "Slow()" would run every frame.
    {
        Slow ();
    }
    waypoint = waypoints[WPindexPointer]; //Keep the object pointed toward the current Waypoint object.
}




//I declared "Accell()".
void  Accell (){
    if (accelState == false) //
    {                   //
        accelState = true;    //Make sure that if Accell() is running, Slow() can not run.
        slowState = false;    //
    }
    //
    //I grabbed this next part from the unity "SmoothLookAt" script but try to explain more.
    if (waypoint) //If there is a waypoint do the next "if".
    {
        if (smoothRotation) //If smoothRotation is set to "On", do the rotation over time with nice ease in and ease out motion.
        {
            //Look at the active waypoint.
            Quaternion rotation= Quaternion.Euler(waypoint.position - transform.position);
            //Make the rotation nice and smooth.
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationDamping);
        }
    }
    //Now do the accelleration toward the active waypoint untill the "speedLimit" is reached
    currentSpeed = currentSpeed + accel * accel;
    transform.Translate (0,0,Time.deltaTime * currentSpeed);

    //When the "speedlimit" is reached or exceeded ...
    if (currentSpeed >= speedLimit)
    {
        // ... turn off accelleration and set "currentSpeed" to be exactly the "speedLimit". Without this, the "currentSpeed will be slightly above "speedLimit"
        currentSpeed = speedLimit;
    }
}




//The function "OnTriggerEnter" is called when a collision happens.
void  OnTriggerEnter (){
    functionState = 1; //When the GameObject collides with the waypoint's collider, activate "Slow()" by setting "functionState" to "1".
    WPindexPointer++;  //When the GameObject collides with the waypoint's collider, change the active waypoint to the next one in the array variable "waypoints".

    //When the array variable reaches the end of the list ...
    if (WPindexPointer >= waypoints.Length)
    {
        WPindexPointer = 0; // ... reset the active waypoint to the first object in the array variable "waypoints" and start from the beginning.
    }
}




//I declared "Slow()".
void  Slow (){
    if (slowState == false) //
    {                  //
        accelState = false; //Make sure that if Slow() is running, Accell() can not run.
        slowState = true;   //
    }                  //

    //Begin to do the slow down (or speed up if inertia is set above "1.0f" in the inspector).
    currentSpeed = currentSpeed * inertia;
    transform.Translate (0,0,Time.deltaTime * currentSpeed);

    //When the "minSpeed" is reached or exceeded ...
    if (currentSpeed <= minSpeed)
    {
        currentSpeed = 0.0f; // ... Stop the movement by setting "currentSpeed to Zero.
                //WaitForSeconds (stopTime); //Wait for the amount of time set in "stopTime" before moving to next waypoint.
        functionState = 0; //Activate the function "Accell()" to move to next waypoint.
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why not use Unity's built in AI pathfinding solution? The navmesh works fine for most AI pathfinding.

Comment: I found the pathfinding scrit in Unity, but I'm not sure how to use it. I googled it, yet i can't seem to find any documentation for it. Can you help with that?

Comment: Like I said earlier, why not use the built in Unity NavMesh system?